# How to use gitignore wth pyc files

Tags: git

In my .gitignore I have the below

```
/path/to/*.pyc
```

Yet pyc files are pushed.  I have tried the above to no avail.

1) I did git rm of al my pyc files and committed.  The were removed from remote
2) I just have *.pyc in the .gitignore

Then after another commit the pyc files are back in my repo.

```
create mode 100644 bootops/classes/__init__.pyc
 create mode 100644 bootops/classes/bootstrap.pyc
 create mode 100644 bootops/classes/doUtilities.pyc
 create mode 100644 bootops/classes/getparms.pyc
 create mode 100644 bootops/classes/health.pyc
 create mode 100644 bootops/classes/libcloud_wrapper.pyc
 create mode 100644 bootops/classes/send_email.pyc
 create mode 100644 bootops/classes/zookeeper_health.pyc
```

Comment: Don't specify a full path in .gitignore; just give the file glob *.pyc.

Answer (score 3):

you have to clean your git cache ...

To resolve your problem use the followings steps:

```
git rm -r --cached .

git add .

git commit -m ".gitignore for pyc is now working"
```

hope it helps

Comment: Describing these steps as "cleaning your git cache" is a serious misstatement of what they do.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `.gitignore` file doesn't remove any existing files from your repository; it just causes any matching files to be ignored when git looks at your working tree for operations like `git status`. If you want to remove the files from the repository, you'll need to do that explicitly using `git rm`. (You may want to use `git rm --cached` to leave the files in your working tree.)

Comment: Hi..as of late I am doing git rm.  The files are being commited regardless.

Comment: If you've really removed the files, they won't be in your repository anymore. Are you adding them back somehow, or…?